# unwanted side margins of my custom listview item layout

Tags: android

I'm getting some weird left and right side margins when using a custom `listview` item layout. They are margins (or at least not padding of the container), since the background doesn't extend to the edge.

In this layout, I'm using a simple vertical `LinearLayout` with a bunch of `textviews` and a `progressbar`. If I switch back the built-in **simple_list_item_activated_1.xml**, the margins disappear. The linear layout itself doesn't have any layout margins. I specifically stripped it of any attributes, leaving only the id, the `layout_width="match_parent"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`, and the margins were still there.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

**A screenshot of the problem can be seen here:**

[image]

**Edit 1:** @Grishu: As I've said earlier, these margins appear even with a very simple layout, such as this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I just typed this from memory, so it might contain syntax errors. But you get the idea.

**Edit2:** I just went over all my layouts. The problematic margin was set on one of the parent containers, thus it has nothing to do with list items. Sorry for the spam.

Comment: Post your layout code please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had a similar problem with a listview item layout, it looked fine in the graphical layout in eclipse, i solved it by setting:

```
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"
```

in the main relative layout, hope this helps.